# [BLE]CBCentralManager(delegate:, queue:) throw exception:'String does not represent a valid UUID' only on IOS 16

Tags: swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager

I try to develop an IOS app using Bluetooth Low Energy to Scan and Advertise data with CoreBluetooth.
With IOS version < 16, My App was work normally

But with IOS 16
The Advertising data work well but when calling Scan:

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class ViewController: UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate{
    var centralManager : CBCentralManager!
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        switch central.state{
            
        case .unknown:
            print("Error!")
        case .resetting:
            print("Error!")
        case .unsupported:
            print("Error!")
        case .unauthorized:
            print("Error!")
        case .poweredOff:
            print("Error!")
        case .poweredOn:
            central.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil)
        @unknown default:
            print("Error!")
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }
    
    
}
```

My app crashed with the exception:

```
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'String  does not represent a valid UUID'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
CoreSimulator 857.13 - Device: iPhone 14 (EF5FBAFD-8E40-4A10-802E-B04B8EC0F1DF) - Runtime: iOS 16.1 (20B72) - DeviceType: iPhone 14
```

Does Anyone get the same issue with me and How did you solve it?

Comment: Are you trying to run on the simulator?  Core Bluetooth is not supported on the simulator.

Comment: I have tried to run on Simulator and real devices too.

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to show relevant code. I really don't think that if you have an app with just `let centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)` in it you will get the crash.  There is something else in your code, possibly in your advertising code, that is causing the problem.

Comment: But I guarantee that if I put that code in an app with nothing else and run it on 16.x it won't crash. You need to do some troubleshooting to work out what is causing the crash. (Although you should ensure that the state is `.poweredOn` before starting your scan)

Comment: I run successfully this code on iOS <16 but with iOS > 16 devices, the app was crashed when execute "centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)" with the log above. And I don't understand the exception.

Comment: I put that code into a brand new Xcode project and it does not crash on iOS 16.4 or iOS 16.5.  I guess it is possible that there is some BLE peripheral in your environment that is triggering a bug in Core Bluetooth, however it is odd that you say you see this crash on the simulator as the simulator cannot see any BLE peripherals. Core Bluetooth is completely non functional on the simulator.

Comment: I found that i add "Bluetooth Services" in Info.plist. It made the app crash on iOS 16(but not on iOS < 16). Thanks for your support

Comment: What "Bluetooth services"?  Bluetooth background capabilities?

Comment: I don't know exactly what it is(It made the app crash only on iOS > 16). That's my mistake when adding capabilities to project.